# Android Text vanishes on map overlay

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, ondraw

I have made an overlay for my mapview. I have drawn markers to show where earthquakes have taken place but I am trying to draw text to show the magnitude of that earthquake next to the marker. The problem is that the text appears but as soon as the map is touched (I think that is when the onDraw for the overlay is executed), the text vanishes. Here is my code. Any will be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class EarthquakeOverlay extends Overlay {
Context c;
int counter = 0;
Cursor earthquakes;
ArrayList<GeoPoint> quakeLocations;
ArrayList<String> mags;
int rad = 5;
String g;

public EarthquakeOverlay(Cursor cursor, Context con) {
    super();
    earthquakes = cursor;
    c = con;
    mags = new ArrayList<String>();
    quakeLocations = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    refreshQuakeLocations();
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    earthquakes = cursor;
    refreshQuakeLocations();
}

private void refreshQuakeLocations() {
    quakeLocations.clear();

    if (earthquakes != null && earthquakes.moveToFirst())
        do {
            int magIndex = earthquakes
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(EarthquakeProvider.KEY_MAGNITUDE);

            String mag = earthquakes.getString(magIndex);

            mags.add(mag);

            int latIndex = earthquakes
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(EarthquakeProvider.KEY_LOCATION_LAT);
            int lngIndex = earthquakes
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(EarthquakeProvider.KEY_LOCATION_LNG);

            Double lat = earthquakes.getFloat(latIndex) * 1E6;
            Double lng = earthquakes.getFloat(lngIndex) * 1E6;

            GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(), lng.intValue());
            quakeLocations.add(geoPoint);

        } while (earthquakes.moveToNext());
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

    Bitmap flag = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(),
            R.drawable.marker);

    Paint bitmapPaint = new Paint();
    bitmapPaint.setFilterBitmap(false);
    bitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Point globalPoint = new Point();

    // Create and setup your paint brush
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);

    if (shadow == false) {
        for (GeoPoint point : quakeLocations) {
            Point myPoint = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(point, myPoint);
            globalPoint = myPoint;


            if (c != null) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(flag, myPoint.x - rad, myPoint.y - rad,
                        bitmapPaint);
                if(mags.isEmpty()){
                // do nothing
                }else{
                    canvas.drawText(mags.get(0), myPoint.x - rad, myPoint.y - rad,
                            paint);
                    mags.remove(0);
                }
            }// end of if stetment


            }// end of quakeLocations for statment

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the following line --

```
 mags.remove(0);
```

After you draw the first time, you remove all the magnitudes from your list, so the next time `draw` is called `mags.isEmpty()` is going to be true.

Looking at your logic, you will need probably need to redo your loop to traverse your two parallel arrays `quakeLocations` and `mags`.

Something like changing `for (GeoPoint point : quakeLocations)` to

```
final int numQuakes = 0;
for(int i=0; i < numQuakes; i++) {
// in here use quakeLocations.get(i) and mags.get(i)
}
```